# It seems that nvidia-smi preserves more GPU memory if the model class is inherited from another nn.Module class?

Tags: pytorch

As title. It seems that nvidia-smi preserves more GPU memory if the model class is inherited from another nn.Module class.

I create a class to implement my algorithm that uses `torch.utils.checkpoint`, then I found that I need to share the implementation for a new model. So I extract it into a base class which is inherited from `nn.Module`. My original model class now has been simplified a lot, but I noticed that the GPU memory usage reported by nvidia-smi is much higher than before: 14450MiB to almost full 22868MiB on Nvidia GeForce RTX 3090.

What could be the reason(s)? Is it possible to make the value lower?